# Is it possible to filter a MongoDB on the value of a field whose value is a list of dictionaries?

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to know if it is possible to get all the documents from a MongoDB database by querying on the elements of a field whose value is a list. For example here `q2.Results` has a list of comments and I would like to get all the documents where the `UserNickname` of the person who wrote the comment is `Jackobear` :

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fd5e617260828c7646000aa"
  },
  "q2": {
    "Id": "q2",
    "Locale": "fr_FR",
    "Results": [
      {
        "Id": "163069310",
        "CID": "eb523c23-980d-5661-b9d0-c6dc1028fa42",
        "SourceClient": "sephora-fr",
        "Badges": {
          "loyaltyYes--Im-a-VIB-Rouge": {
            "ContentType": "REVIEW",
            "Id": "loyaltyYes--Im-a-VIB-Rouge",
            "BadgeType": "Custom"
          }
        },
        "BadgesOrder": [
          "loyaltyYes--Im-a-VIB-Rouge"
        ],
        "LastModeratedTime": "2020-09-22T12:00:18.000+00:00",
        "LastModificationTime": "2020-12-10T14:36:16.000+00:00",
        "ProductId": "P3742199",
        "CampaignId": "BV_PIE_ONLINE",
        "ContextDataValuesOrder": [
          "Gender",
          "Eyes",
          "Skin"
        ],
        "UserLocation": "Paris",
        "AuthorId": "78948942",
        "ContentLocale": "fr_FR",
        "IsFeatured": false,
        "TotalInappropriateFeedbackCount": {
          "$numberInt": "0"
        },
        "TotalClientResponseCount": {
          "$numberInt": "0"
        },
        "TotalCommentCount": {
          "$numberInt": "0"
        },
        "Rating": {
          "$numberInt": "5"
        },
        "IsRatingsOnly": false,
        "IsRecommended": true,
        "Helpfulness": {
          "$numberDouble": "1.0"
        },
        "TotalFeedbackCount": {
          "$numberInt": "2"
        },
        "TotalNegativeFeedbackCount": {
          "$numberInt": "0"
        },
        "TotalPositiveFeedbackCount": {
          "$numberInt": "2"
        },
        "ModerationStatus": "APPROVED",
        "SubmissionId": "r23232-fr__16007743UA3Zr3O9L5",
        "SubmissionTime": "2020-09-22T11:32:57.000+00:00",
        "ReviewText": "J’adore, il sent le bord de mer une ressemblance avec le parfum Kenzo",
        "Title": "Très bon parfum",
        "UserNickname": "Jackobear",
        "ContextDataValues": {
          "Gender": {
            "Value": "Male",
            "Id": "Gender"
          },
          "Skin": {
            "Value": "Normale",
            "Id": "Skin"
          },
          "Eyes": {
            "Value": "Marrons",
            "Id": "Eyes"
          }
        },
        "Videos": [],
        "Pros": null,
        "InappropriateFeedbackList": [],
        "SecondaryRatings": {},
        "ClientResponses": [],
        "Photos": [],
        "Cons": null,
        "IsSyndicated": false,
        "SecondaryRatingsOrder": [],
        "AdditionalFields": {},
        "RatingRange": {
          "$numberInt": "5"
        },
        "TagDimensions": {},
        "AdditionalFieldsOrder": [],
        "ProductRecommendationIds": [],
        "CommentIds": [],
        "TagDimensionsOrder": []
      },
      {
        "Id": "129228166",
        "CID": "66aec0c2-04b0-57d2-aa9f-ac3b7ecb91df",
        "SourceClient": "sephora-fr",
        "Badges": {
          "loyaltyYes--Im-a-beauty-insider": {
            "ContentType": "REVIEW",
            "Id": "loyaltyYes--Im-a-beauty-insider",
            "BadgeType": "Custom"
          }
        },
        "BadgesOrder": [
          "loyaltyYes--Im-a-beauty-insider"
        ],
        "LastModeratedTime": "2019-06-12T00:15:07.000+00:00",
        "LastModificationTime": "2020-02-07T10:11:38.000+00:00",
        "ProductId": "P3742199",
        "CampaignId": "BV_REVIEW_DISPLAY",
        "ContextDataValuesOrder": [
          "Gender",
          "Age",
          "Eyes",
          "Skin"
        ],
        "UserLocation": "Bayeux",
        "AuthorId": "78051240",
        "ContentLocale": "fr_FR",
        "IsFeatured": false,
        "InappropriateFeedbackList": [
          {
            "AuthorId": "ztn5x2jvnf5u8llq2jagt7j4mp",
            "SubmissionTime": "2019-06-11T23:12:44.000+00:00"
          },
          {
            "AuthorId": "zpebdw7hh48w5zpr3778nx2hgg",
            "SubmissionTime": "2019-06-06T23:20:57.000+00:00"
          },
          {
            "AuthorId": "zkvy1qeaaz8s2znk6kesfg3dnb",
            "SubmissionTime": "2019-06-03T20:01:34.000+00:00"
          }
        ],
        "TotalInappropriateFeedbackCount": {
          "$numberInt": "3"
        },
        "TotalClientResponseCount": {
          "$numberInt": "0"
        },
        "TotalCommentCount": {
          "$numberInt": "0"
        },
        "Rating": {
          "$numberInt": "5"
        },
        "IsRatingsOnly": false,
        "IsRecommended": true,
        "Helpfulness": {
          "$numberDouble": "0.8999999761581421"
        },
        "TotalFeedbackCount": {
          "$numberInt": "40"
        },
        "TotalNegativeFeedbackCount": {
          "$numberInt": "4"
        },
        "TotalPositiveFeedbackCount": {
          "$numberInt": "36"
        },
        "ModerationStatus": "APPROVED",
        "SubmissionId": "halilss25hcanccb0yj6nxvpk",
        "SubmissionTime": "2019-06-03T11:43:04.000+00:00",
        "ReviewText": "Un parfum enivrant mais pas entêtant, la note de tête est exquise et très fraîche, parfaite pour l'été. Vous devriez vendre ce parfum dans plus de sephora et avec plus de stock!!",
        "Title": "Parfait pour l'été",
        "UserNickname": "Abraxas",
        "ContextDataValues": {
          "Age": {
            "Value": "18to24",
            "Id": "Age"
          },
          "Gender": {
            "Value": "Female",
            "Id": "Gender"
          },
          "Skin": {
            "Value": "Grasse",
            "Id": "Skin"
          },
          "Eyes": {
            "Value": "Bleus",
            "Id": "Eyes"
          }
        },
        "Videos": [],
        "Pros": null,
        "SecondaryRatings": {},
        "ClientResponses": [],
        "Photos": [],
        "Cons": null,
        "IsSyndicated": false,
        "SecondaryRatingsOrder": [],
        "AdditionalFields": {},
        "RatingRange": {
          "$numberInt": "5"
        },
        "TagDimensions": {},
        "AdditionalFieldsOrder": [],
        "ProductRecommendationIds": [],
        "CommentIds": [],
        "TagDimensionsOrder": []
      }
    ],
    "HasErrors": false,
    "Errors": []
  },
  "name": "L'Atelier des Subtils Eau d'Océan - Eau de toilette",
}
```

I was thinking of a cause like doing a `find_all` with:

```
users = ['Jackobear']
collection.findall({'q2.Results.x.UserNickname' : {'$in': users}})
```

If it is not possible, I suppose I have to make a new database with the perfumes appreciated by each person? How can I make the script that could retrieve this information from the database by searching these documents for each user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$match` to filter the records 1st so that `$unwind` will have fewer records to deal with.
- `$unwind` to break into individual documents.
- Now perform match on individual documents.

You can use $group to group documents.

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "q2.Results.UserNickname": { $in: [ "Jackobear", "ABC" ] } } },
  { $unwind: "$q2.Results" },
  { $match: { "q2.Results.UserNickname": { $in: [ "Jackobear", "ABC" ] } } }
])
```

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/g04J8f4-TjY

Comment: Many thanks! And do you know how I can return only a specific field then? Like `name` (the very last field)

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica Read - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/